# Custom label not aligning horizontally in ASP.NET charts

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

I am binding datatable to ASP.NET chart for which I am using custom label for X-Axis. The label text is aligned vertically and the chart size gets reduced.

I tried the following code :

```
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsLabelAutoFit = false;
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Enabled = true;
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Comic Sans", 9F);
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.WordWrap;
```

I also tried the following fix by searching the internet:

```
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
Chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.LabelsAngleStep90;
```

I tried changing various values for the angle but still it would align vertically.

Any links or suggestion on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am Ultra New, but this may help:" i have been searching for a solution for the last 4 hrs and someone suggested using annotations. Also this code is in VB, but it may help with another direction if you can't find an answer.

```
Dim MyTextAnnotation As TextAnnotation
                MyTextAnnotation = New TextAnnotation
                MyTextAnnotation.Text = "some notation"
                MyTextAnnotation.X = 0
                MyTextAnnotation.Y = 0
                chart1.Annotations.Add(MyTextAnnotation)
```